# Positioning HTML divs so that one would be smaller than the other

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that is best represented by a wire-frame, which I'm attaching. I need a way to structure the page so that the registration area (the one with input fields in the wire-frame) is bigger than the area to the left of it (a picture will be displayed in that smaller area).

**Question**: what would be the best way to go about it, using as simple HTML and CSS as possible?

**My attempts**: I have tried one possible way, however it is just a hack with the margin-top CSS property.

```css
        * {
            /* box-sizing: border-box; */
          }
    
          .row {
            background-color: transparent;
            margin: auto;
            width: 75%;
          }
    
          /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    
          .column {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 10px;
            /* height: 200%; */
          }
    
          /* Clear floats after the columns */
    
          .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
          }
    
          #c1 {
            background-color: #aaa;
            width: 30%;
            margin-top: 4%;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
          }
    
          #c2 {
            /* width: 60%; */
            background-color: #bbb;
          }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#ddc;">
  <h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="c1">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="c2">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Using margins is not a hack, it is, combined with positioning, what one use to accomplish what you ask. In your case, if the left hand element has a padding, an inner element holding the image would also appear to be a viable option in this case. The benefit with that is that it would be dynamic, where one or the other would adjust to the others content, which e.g. fixed height doesn't.

Comment: And btw, there is no _best way_, there is only different solutions to accomplish the same outcome, hence your question is off topic/too broad.

Comment: @LGSon I mostly agree, to what you said, I called it a hack since it's not dynamic and does not keep proportions when resolution varies. I shoud also have used a "better way", instead of the best.

Comment: Actually, even with _better way_ your question is off topic, being both too broad and primarily opinion-based. Instead rephrase it and ask how to make it dynamic/content based (where Flexbox/CSS Grid is the one's that has the ability to make them grow equally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but here is one potential way. hope is helps :)

as requested some explanation:

The key things to know here are the css properties display, text-align and vertical-align.

display: inline-block; tells the elements they should sit side by side

vertical-align: tells the elements they should vertically center within their container

text-align: center; tells the container to center the inline-block elements inside.

font-size: 0; on the container is just because inline-block adds a mystery space.

Thats really simple explanation but I would recommend heading over to w3schools to review he properties and their behaviours.
https://www.w3schools.com/

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row {
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
}


.small {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.large {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small">a</div>
  <div class="large">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: using flexbox or even absolute position could also be good options for you.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @digital-pollution - Yes, this was helpful. I would accept the answer, but please add some details why / how the issue is solved by the code added.

Comment: I put in some basic explanation, others have given flex examples which are good and more modern techniques if browser support isn't such a concern for you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Hope this is what you need.
flexbox gives more efficiency in aligning items.

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <style>
     div {
     border: 1px solid #000; 
     }

    .inner {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center; /* if you want space between image and content then use space-evenly */
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 0;
    }


    .image {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 200px;
     font-size: 12px;
    }

    .content {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 250px;
     height: 300px;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <div class="inner">
   <div class="image"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:#d9d9ff;
}

.small{
  background-color:#caffff;
  flex: .25;
}
.big{
  padding:1rem 0 1rem 0;
  background-color:#f5c0c0;
  flex: .25;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="small">Small</div>
  <div class="big">Big</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use **flexbox**. Center the columns vertically and horizontally:

```
.vh {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

### In total

```css
* {
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

body {
  background: #ddc;
}

.row {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  /* height: 200%; */
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

#c1 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#c2 {
  /* width: 60%; */
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" id="c1">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="c2">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```